# Looping a string formula + variable into a “real” formula

Tags: excel, vba

I am struggling with my Excelsheet. I have a two-fold question regarding *x* in cell B1 
the following formula:

```
=IF(A1=1,"=INDEX(Sheet1!B:B,MATCH(x,Sheet1!A:A,0))",IF(A1=2,"=INDEX(Sheet1!B:B,MATCH(x,Sheet2!A:A,0))",IF(A1=3,"=INDEX(Sheet1!B:B,MATCH(x,Sheet1!A:A,0))","=INDEX(Sheet1!B:B,MATCH(x,Sheet1!A:A,0))")))
```

(1)

Cell B1 displays a "string"-formula depending on the value in cell A1. Idealy, I want to make *x* a variable that I can define with VBA.

```
Sub Test() 
Dim rng As Rang, cell As Range
Set rng = Range("A2:A10")
For Each cell In rng 
cell.Formula = "INDIRECT(?)...

Next cell
```

Which would basically translate to (if Cell A1 = 1):

```
=INDEX(Sheet1!B:B,MATCH(cell,Sheet1!A:A,0))
```

Ideally, I would like to loop this. So, for, example, cell A2 becomes:

```
=INDEX(Sheet1!B:B,MATCH(A2,Sheet1!A:A,0))
```

How can I write this int a VBA-module?

(2)

If cell A2 consist of the discused "string"-formula, how do I calculate it and make it a hard value?

Thank you very very much

**//// Edit ////**

So, in cell B1 I have the following formula

```
=IF(A1=1,"=INDEX(Sheet1!B:B,MATCH(",IF(A1=2,"=INDEX(Sheet1!B:B,MATCH(A2,Sheet2!A:A,0))",IF(A1=3,"=INDEX(Sheet1!B:B,MATCH(A2,Sheet1!A:A,0))","=INDEX(Sheet1!B:B,MATCH(A2,Sheet1!A:A,0))")))
```

In cell I1 I have the following formula:

```
=",Sheet1!A:A,0))"
```

I have written the following macro:

```
Sub Test_3() 
Dim x As Long, lastRow As Long
lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

For x = 2 To lastRow
    Address = Cells(x, 1).Address
    xFormula = Cells(1, 2).Value
    yFormula = Cells(1, 9).Value
    Cells(x, 3).Formula = "=INDIRECT(xFormula & Address & yFormula)"
Next
End Sub
```

The goal of this macro is get the following output, in for example, Cell C3:

```
=INDEX(Sheet1!B:B,MATCH(A3,Sheet1!A:A,0)
```

However, the output of the macro is *#NAME?* with the following formula:

```
=INDIRECT(xFormula & Address & yFormula)
```

I hope this explanation is more clear

Comment: `cell.Formula = "INDIRECT(...)"` needs an `=` sign before `INDIRECT`.

Comment: I'm having a hard time following all this, but I can help thinking this is an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Could you post sample data and expected output?

Comment: What is your value of `A1`, as that is the value of `Address`

Comment: The value of A1 is 1